# Semantics of operator $\times$ with regards to sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, associativity

I am trying to understand something about operator $\times$ with regards of sets. In the accepted answer to the following question ([The cross product of two sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229083/the-cross-product-of-two-sets)), the answerer says that $A \times B$ is the set of ordered pairs, taking their first element in $A$ and their second element in $B$.

So:

- $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is the set of all pairs $(x,y)$ with $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $y \in \mathbb{N}$. It is also called $\mathbb{N}^2$.

But:

- $\mathbb{N}^3$ is the set of all 3-tuples $(x,y,z)$ with $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $y \in \mathbb{N}$ and $z \in \mathbb{N}$. But I have trouble saying it is $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.

Indeed, as few as I understand operators, I think $\times$ is a binary operator on sets, and as such, $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ should be read either as $(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}) \times \mathbb{N}$, or $\mathbb{N} \times (\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N})$, and have semantics:

- $(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}) \times \mathbb{N}$ is the set of all pairs $((x,y),z)$ with $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $y \in \mathbb{N}$ and $z \in \mathbb{N}$.
- $\mathbb{N} \times (\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N})$ is the set of all pairs $(x,(y,z))$ with $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $y \in \mathbb{N}$ and $z \in \mathbb{N}$.

But in no case can I construct a 3-tuple this way.

So my question is: what is the semantics of $\times$? Does it mean "take one element from each set and put them into a pair?" Or is it tuple concatenation, in which case there seems to be missing an operation that maps the set $\mathbb{N}$ to the set of 1-tuples taking thein values in $\mathbb{N}$?

And how do you concisely write the set of ordered triplets that take their first value in $\mathbb{N}$, their second value in $\mathbb{Z}$ and their third value in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: How comfortable are you with basic category theory? I would say the "meaning" of product can best be gotten to there.

Comment: Here is the wiki http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28category_theory%29

Comment: @Rachmaninoff: "There are objects and arrows and arrows turning arrows to arrows and objects to objects. Diagrams have to commute. Long live Chasles." That's about it.

Comment: @Rachmaninoff: Oh, I see. It makes a lot more sense when defining these expressions in terms of the *big pi* summation. $\times$ would not be a binary operator, but just a convenient notation for the *big pi* applied on two elements, and chaining them without parentheses vould mean applying *big pi* on the $n$ elements.

Comment: I think of products as limits over small discrete categories. this captures the "structural meaning". There may be many sets and projection maps which satisfy the limit property, but they are always isomorphic up to unique isomorphism. So I tend not to worry about the details of what the set is in terms of elements since all we really care about is the limit property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I learned set theory (I'm sure there are other entirely valid ways) we started with the following construction. Let $A, B, C, (A_i)_{i \in I}$ be sets.

Define $A \times B = \{(a, b) \mid a \in A, b \in B\}$. This is the usual cartesian product of sets (where, most likely, we define $(a, b) = \{a, \{a,b\}\}$). This is a well-defined construction, and as noted is not in any way associative. By inspection of elements in the corresponding sets, $A \times (B \times C) \neq (A \times B) \times C$.

To define ordered *tuples* of elements, we use a different construction entirely. Suppose that we want to define $A^I := \prod_{i \in I}A_i$ (where this is meant to refer to an ordered tuple of elements). The way we do this is via the following:
$$
\prod_{i \in I}A_i = \Big\{ f: I \to \coprod_{i \in I}A_i \Big| f(i) \in A_i\Big\}
$$
that is, we take it as the set of all functions from the index set to the disjoint union of the $A_i$ such that the value of $f(i) \in A_i$. For example, if $I = 3 = \{0,1,2\}$, and $A_i = \mathbb{N}$, then we would have
$$
\mathbb{N}^3 = \big\{f : \{0,1,2\} \to \mathbb{N} \sqcup \mathbb{N} \sqcup\mathbb{N} \big| f(i) \in \mathbb{N}\big\} \cong \big\{f :\{0,1,2\} \to \mathbb{N}\big\}
$$
which if you play around with this, you should see that this is just a somewhat strange description of the set of ordered triples of elements in $\mathbb{N}$.

Note that in this case the notation $\mathbb{N}^3$ makes perfect sense as a set of tuples, with no concern about associativity.

Now, you may ask why is my definition better than defining it as $\mathbb{N} \times(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N})$ and just working with that?

Well, the point is that any sensible notion of ordered (say) triples will all be canonically in bijection with each other. That is, there is a bijection from my set $\mathbb{N}^3$ to your set $\mathbb{N} \times(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N})$, and between these two and, say, $(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N})\times\mathbb{N}$. In the end it doesn't actually matter which representation we choose, from the perspective of (most) properties we are interested in these three sets are indistinguishable from each other. So you can work with your favourite, I can work with mine, and we have (canonical) ways of translating between them.

Basically, we don't really care *what* $A \times B \times C$ is, as long as it behaves the way we think it ought to. The reason that we have these myriad constructions is just, in a sense, a way to ensure that something that looks like this actually does exist. Once we've done that, it is often best to forget about the details of the construction and think more about what you want that set to be able to do (generally, in relation to other sets).

Comment: Ah, good. Thank you. I do care about internal structure, because I want the cardinality of $\lbrace (a,b,c), (a,(b,c)) \rbrace$ to be $2$ and not $1$. Constructing tuples as a function seems to be the only sensible thing to do.

Comment: Are you aware of any existing notation that would transform a set $S$ into the set of 1-tuples over $S$? Maybe $S^1$?

Comment: Ah, so you may be in the case that I was eliding past: we only care about our specific model if somehow the internal structure of the set is relevant (which is, in my personal experience, exactly never---but that's based on my interests). You could always define $S^1$ as you did, and that would give you the set of functions $\{f : \{0\} \to S\}$, which is in canonical bijection with $S$ itself, but is technically a different set.

Comment: I suppose it all depends on why you want to look at 1-tuples of elements of $S$ instead of $S$ itself. Without knowing that, I can't really specify more.

Comment: Modeling semantics of a programming language. You can concatenate 2 1-tuples to make a 2-tuple, but concatenating the numbers $1$ and $1$ does not make sense. (as members of $\mathbb{N}$)

Comment: Well, it *can* make sense---there is (as a few of us have said) a canonical bijection between, say, $\mathbb{N}$ and the set of 1-tuples in $\mathbb{N}$. So you can always concatenate the latter.

I mean, does it really matter if we define $1 * 1 = (1, 1)$ or $(1) * (1) = (1,1)$? In a certain sense, we're just abusing notation in the former case, but you can always put that in as a side remark.

Comment: I accept that there is a canonical bijection, and that if you are using the $\times$ operator in day-to-day mathematics trying to prove things totally unrelated to the internal structure of these sets, I'm not against abusing the notation a little. But here, I'm trying to model data structures, and *nesting* and *sequence* are not the same thing, and I am looking for a clear semantics for both.

Comment: Well, I would try to do that by introducing more than one operation as opposed to trying to get $\times$ to do both of these. If you do that, you should probably be able to avoid talking about internal structure of the sets, which honestly doesn't seem like its necessary to model data structures to me. That said, I should freely admit that I am not an expert on this.

Comment: Agreed. I was not trying to make $\times$ do all of those. I was just wondering about $\times$, and whether $A \times B \times C$ was constructing a set of 2-tuples or a set of 3-tuples. I think I'll base my definitions on the *big pi* product of a family of sets, use $A^1$ to elevate a set to the set of 1-tuples over it, and call $\times$ a "convenient notation" instead of a binary operator. And find another operator for concatenating tuplesets.

Comment: I (finally) got my head around universal product (and coproduct) thanks to this, and Rachmaninoff's comments and pointers. Thank you.

Comment: And I understand that universal product per se does not produce tuples, just a new set (in the case of the $Set$ category) from which you can extract its "components" with a set of functions called projections. This makes a lot more sense to say that $\mathbb{N}^1 = \mathbb{N}$ in this context. The definition of tuples you gave suits me and I'll definitely use it.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, strictly speaking, $\times$ is not associative as an operator on sets. However, there are natural isomorphisms $(\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N})\times \mathbb{N}\simeq\mathbb{N}\times(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})\simeq\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\ $ given by flattening the parentheses, and this is good enough for most applications.

Comment: Of course, that does tell me what $\times$ is not, not its semantics. Is it correct to write $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}^3$.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA The lack of parentheses indicates that you are considering ordered triples in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty here is that $X^3$ is not *equal* to either $(X \times X) \times X$ or $X \times (X \times X)$. To recall:
$$\begin{align}
X^3 & = \{ (x,y,z) : x \in X, y \in X, z \in X \} \\
(X \times X) \times X & = \{ ((x,y),z) : x \in X, y \in X, z \in X \} \\
X \times (X \times X) & = \{ (x,(y,z)) : x \in X, y \in X, z \in X \} \\
\end{align}$$
In fact none of these three sets are equal (unless $X = \emptyset$, a special case). However, there exist *canonical* bijections between the three, informally:
$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto (x,(y,z)) \qquad (x,y,z) \mapsto ((x,y),z)$$
(Here the word "canonical" means that the three functors $\mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{Set}$, $X \mapsto X^3$ (resp. $X \times (X \times X)$, resp. $(X \times X) \times X)$ are isomorphic. If you don't know what that means don't worry too much.)

So in day-to-day math we can just assume that these three sets are equal and use whichever representation is the most useful. But if you wanted to be perfectly precise and rigorous, they are actually different sets.

Comment: I guess you'll have to precise which one you mean if you ever want to extract the second element of either one. So what is the semantics of $\times$? And, first and foremost, is $\mathbb{N}^3$ the same as $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The thing is that $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is not defined because $\times$ is not associative. But since it's associative up to isomorphism (bijection), you can assume it's whichever of the three possibilities, since they are all in bijection with one another.

Comment: It is not associative, indeed. Is it correct to write $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}^3$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I'd say $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ can be defined by virtue of the fact that there are such things as ordered triples. Maybe it's not standard though.

Comment: Sofar, I can accept that writing $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is ambiguous, because $\times$ is not associative. Okay. So in $\forall (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{N}^3$, $\mathbb{N}^3$ is the set of ordered triples with values in $\mathbb{N}$, right? In that case, is there a concise standard way of describing the set of ordered triples that take their first value in $\mathbb{N}$, their second value in $\mathbb{Z}$ and their third value in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You can write just write it as $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}$. As I said, since there is a canonical bijection between all these sets, you can basically consider them all as equal without any ill effects.

Comment: But then, if I am saying $\forall (n,z,r) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R} ...$ somewhere, it's not hard to get a tautology because there is no triplet in a set of pairs. I fail again to fathom the meaning of $\times$.