# How can I visualize the Cartesian product of sets?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I saw the question asking about intervals and simple Cartesian products, but how can I visualize things like $S^1 \times S^1$, the Cartesian product of the unit 1-sphere? I understand that this is a Torus, but what should my thought process be here?

Comment: Think of a circle, drawn through space along some circular path, until you get back to the same circle again. The locus of all points any point on the circle has moved through is a picture of the torus. Unfortunately this is impossible for many spaces, and we have to resort to less accurate visualizations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of $X \times Y$ as substituting a copy of $Y$ for each $x \in X$. For spaces (and other kinds of structures, e.g. orderings), each copy $Y_x = Y$ of $Y$ retains its notion of "nearness", but the notion of nearness on $X$ is also retained: for $x, ', x'' \in X$, if $x$ is nearer to $x'$ than to $x''$, and if $y \in Y$, then the copy $(x,y)$ in $Y_x$ will be nearer to the copy $(x', y)$ in $Y_{x'}$ than to the copy $(x'',y)$ in $Y_{x''}$.

In the case of $S^1 \times S^1$, you're replacing every point on the (first) circle with a copy of the second space (another unit circle), taking care to define the neighborhoods so that "nearness" is as described before.

Similarly, orderings $X, Y$ give rise to an ordering on $X \times Y$ – the dictionary or lexicographic order. Again you can think of it as substituting a copy of $Y$ for each $x \in X$. For example, where $3$ is the 3-element set $\{0,1,2\}$ with the usual ordering, then $3 \times \mathbb{N}$ with the dictionary order looks like this:
$$
0, 1, 2, \dots, 0', 1', 2', \dots, 0'', 1'', 2'', \dots \text{.}
$$

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for in a clear and concise response. When I read it I realized I went through this exact thought process back when I took Differential Geometry three years ago, I'd just forgotten.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Of course i had to handwave about "nearness". Fortunately there's a sharp definition of it (the product topology).  @Kevin Carlson is saying pretty much the same thing about visualizing the torus, and he's right, the thought experiment may not be possible with some pairs of spaces... but even then it's useful to try.

Comment: Reference to good visualization on math.stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/229084/81829

Answer (score 8):

A pair of angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ determine an element $(e^{i\theta},e^{i\phi})$ in $S^1\times S^1$, which in order they can be consider that give a position in the torus.

This is achieved mapping via $(e^{i\theta},e^{i\phi})\longrightarrow\left((2+\cos\theta)\cos\phi,(2+\cos\theta)\sin\phi,\sin\theta\right)$

In the picture, the **blue point** on the torus is specified by the **two angles** in green.

[image: torus]

Comment: Thanks! Great response! Probably only superseded by the quickness of the previous response.